# viewing user requested slurm job priority

Tags: slurm

I submitted the below job in slurm

```
testuser1@dev-0:~$ sbatch --priority=10 --cpus-per-task=10 --wrap="/bin/sleep 300"
Submitted batch job 18
```

When I do show job on the above one, I don't see the above submitted priority value in scontrol show job.

```
testuser1@dev-0:~$ scontrol show job 18
JobId=18 JobName=wrap
UserId=testuser1(1000) GroupId=tstgrp00(1000) MCS_label=N/A
Priority=4294901751 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=(null)
JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
RunTime=00:00:15 TimeLimit=365-00:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
SubmitTime=2023-10-03T09:59:44 EligibleTime=2023-10-03T09:59:44
AccrueTime=2023-10-03T09:59:44
StartTime=2023-10-03T09:59:44 EndTime=2024-10-02T09:59:44 Deadline=N/A
SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2023-10-03T09:59:44 Scheduler=Backfill
Partition=debug AllocNode:Sid=dev-0:116
ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
NodeList=dev-0
BatchHost=dev-0
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=10 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=10 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
ReqTRES=cpu=10,mem=10M,node=1,billing=10
AllocTRES=cpu=10,mem=10M,node=1,billing=10
Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
MinCPUsNode=10 MinMemoryCPU=1M MinTmpDiskNode=0
Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
Command=(null)
WorkDir=/home/testuser1
StdErr=/home/testuser1/slurm-18.out
StdIn=/dev/null
StdOut=/home/testuser1/slurm-18.out
Power=
```

The scheduler type in my slurm.conf is sched/backfill. Although the jobs are being scheduled as per the user requested priority but I don't see the exact value requested by user in `scontrol show job`. I am seeing this value even with sacct. Is there a way to view the original value in scontrol?

Answer (score 0):

If your printed priorty value is say `X`,

then the actual priority can be calculated as

```
 UINT_MAX - UINT16_MAX + 1 - X
```

So, in your case, it will be,

```
 UINT_MAX - UINT16_MAX + 1 - 4294901751
```

can be translated as

```
 4294967295 - 65535 + 1 - 4294901751 #will give 10
```

Slurm sets the priority in unsigned integers and when displaying the result, (*FOLLOWING IS MY ASSUMPTION - I didn't check the entire code :)*) the translation (format specifiers/different types in different data structures for storing job information) messes (unsigned int and unsigned short) and priority calculation is shown as large values in the output (or maybe they intended it to be in such a way). Hence, doing the reverse engineering scenario mentioned above can get you the output.

```
MAX Values:
    UNIT_MAX 4294967295
    UINT16_MAX 65535
```

This is my assumption!

Comment: Thanks for the calculative answer. I was wondering why this bigger number from `show job` for priority and from the documentation it seems like normal users anyway cannot set the priority of the job. It will be allowed only to privileged users. If I set the priority as root, I see the number 10.